# Xpages toolbar with nested repeat controls - @DbLookup unable to access var value of parent repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a toolbar that should allow users to select the make of a car. The makes are pulled through using the var request scope variable in the repeat control. However, when I try and access the corresponding values using @DbLookup, it fails to return anything. Below is the code snippet:

```
<xe:toolbar id="toolbar1" showButtonLabels="true">
  <xe:this.treeNodes>
    <xe:pageTreeNode label="Make">
      <xe:this.children>
        <xe:repeatTreeNode indexVar="index"
        loaded="true" var="varValue">
          <xe:this.value>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbColumn("", "parts list", 1))}]]>
          </xe:this.value>
          <xe:this.children>
            <xe:pageTreeNode
            label="#{javascript:varValue}">
              <xe:this.children>
                <xe:repeatTreeNode
                indexVar="index1" loaded="true" var="varValue1">
                  <xe:this.value>
                    <![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbLookup("", "parts list", requestScope.varValue, 2))}]]>
                  </xe:this.value>
                  <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode
                    label="#{javascript:requestScope.varValue1}">
                    </xe:pageTreeNode>
                  </xe:this.children>
                </xe:repeatTreeNode>
              </xe:this.children>
            </xe:pageTreeNode>
          </xe:this.children>
        </xe:repeatTreeNode>
      </xe:this.children>
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode label="Vehicle">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
  </xe:this.treeNodes>
  <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
  refreshMode="partial" refreshId="toolbar1">
  </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:toolbar>
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Or how can I gain access to the varValue variable on the selected item in the first list?

An example of what I want is under the toolbar tab in the following link:
http://www.xpages.jp/demos/xpagesext.nsf/Core_Outline.xsp
Also, I am new to xpages. Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you try to use distinct names. You have a repeat var and a scope var with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toolbar renders into the XPages component tree as a single component. So it is quite hard to get hands on any values. When you render repeat controls in a different context, things work quite nicely. For the toolbar you could use an ugly hack like the one below, or you render your specific toolbar in a manual control using repeats. I got this sample to work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
        <xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var result = new java.util.LinkedList();
    var allMakes = @Unique(@DbColumn("", "parts list", 1));
    for (var makeIndex in allMakes) {
       var curModelName = allMakes[makeIndex];
       var someModels = @Unique(@DbLookup("", "parts list", curModelName, 2));
       if (someModels != null) {
          result.offer(someModels);
          result.offer(someModels);
       }
    }
    viewScope.ModelsAndMakes = result;   }]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
        <xe:toolbar id="toolbar1" showButtonLabels="true">
            <xe:this.treeNodes>
                <xe:pageTreeNode label="Make">
                    <xe:this.children>
                        <xe:repeatTreeNode indexVar="indexMakes" loaded="true"
                            var="varMakes">

                            <xe:this.children>
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="#{varMakes}">
                                    <xe:this.children>
                                        <xe:repeatTreeNode indexVar="indexModel"
                                            loaded="true" var="varModel">

                                            <xe:this.children>
                                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="#{varModel}">
                                                </xe:pageTreeNode>
                                            </xe:this.children>
                                            <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (view.isRenderingPhase()) {
        return viewScope.ModelsAndMakes.poll();
    };}]]></xe:this.value>
                                        </xe:repeatTreeNode>
                                        <xe:basicLeafNode label="Fixed ende after">
                                        </xe:basicLeafNode>
                                    </xe:this.children>
                                </xe:pageTreeNode>
                            </xe:this.children>
                            <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbColumn("", "parts list", 1))}]]></xe:this.value>
                        </xe:repeatTreeNode>
                    </xe:this.children>
                </xe:pageTreeNode>

            </xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="toolbar1">
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xe:toolbar>
        <ol>
            <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="outerList" indexVar="outerIndex">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbColumn("", "parts list", 1))}]]></xp:this.value>
                <li>
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" tagName="h3"
                        value="#{outerList}">
                    </xp:text>
                    <ol>
                        <xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="30" var="innerList">
                            <xe:this.value>
                            <![CDATA[#{javascript:@Unique(@DbLookup("", "parts list", outerList, 2))}]]>
                            </xe:this.value>
                            <li>
                                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{innerList}">
                                </xp:text>
                            </li>
                        </xp:repeat>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </xp:repeat>
        </ol>
    </xp:view>
```

The double entries in the result.offer is necessary since the lifecyle polls twice. As I said: ***ugly hack*** Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi stwissel. Thanks so much for your assistance. Unfortunately this implementation is not feasible at this stage so I've taken another approach that being: Creating combo boxes to display these values. Again, thanks very much for the assistance. It truly is appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use something I label "ugly hack" in an application anyway. As you saw in the example, a normal repeat control works the way you would expect. When you check the OneUI you can render the menu like the TreeNode would do.. Btw. the Stackoverflow standard of thank you is upvote and/or accept an answer